# PHP return only last row JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

Since few days, I search a soluce for my problem : My PHP return only the last row. This JSON data will be parsed for jsPDF later.

My PHP who get sql data and convert JSON :

```
    $nexans = json_decode($_GET['nexans'], true);

 $tab_req = array();
   foreach ($nexans as $key => $value) {
         $req_jsonmultipdf = $maPdoFonction->PDF_Multi($key,$value,$_SESSION['ssetablissement_id'],'4','NEXANS');
     $tab_req[] = $req_jsonmultipdf->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }

        $retour = array(
                 "success" => true,
                 "data" => $tab_req
              );

    echo json_encode($tab_req);
```

This PHP return only last row and so my table in jsPDF have only one row. How to fix it please ? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you

```
   $tab_req = array();
   foreach ($newarr as $key => $value) {
         $req_jsonmultipdf = $maPdoFonction->PDF_Multi($key,$value,$_SESSION['ssetablissement_id'],'4','NEXANS');
         $tab_req[] = $req_jsonmultipdf->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

   $retour = array(
                 "success" => true,
                 "data" => $tab_req
           );
```

Explanation. You always overwrite your var $req_jsonmultipdf by the last of your loop.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver for your answer. But now, my PHP return nothing :/. I have edited the first post with your answer

Comment: That was not a good idea :-) I have adjusted my answer to your  editing. Of course the first loop is missing now, where your $newarr has been build. without that, there is no data to loop over... and the echo json_encode is missing too. Would be better to recreate your code and just adjust the part, where I have made changes...

Comment: Thanks again @Oliver. I get my PHP JSON work. So, now I get a array in array, right?

Comment: yes, now you add each row to an array and you will  not overwrite it anymore. The rest will be done by json_encode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I will be obliged to create a new thread, because I don't know how to get each element in a row, because my row is always in a array when I parse my JSON ...